# ModuleNotFound Error : Mysql module is not being found?

Tags: python, mysql

My system doesn't seem to be willing to find the mysql module. After trying allot I still get the Modulenotfound Error: No module named mysql.
This is what I've done so far:

1.
`pip install mysqlclient`

2.

```
`pip install mysql-connector`
```

3. 

`pip install mysql-connector-python`

This didn't seem to work so I did the following:

`pip install -U setuptools`

but this also didn't seem to work.

Furthermore, my system can't seem to find mysql-connector-python-rf

Any guesses on what might go wrong here?

Comment: Also, when I run import mysql in the terminal it does work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be installing those packages in a different interpreter than the one you're using to run your script, the best way IMO to avoid these kind of errors is by using a virtual environment.

To set up a venv, go to your projects folder and execute the following:

```
python -m venv ./env
```

And then:
(Windows)

```
./env/Scripts/activate
```

Or if you're on linux:

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

Then you should reinstall every dependence and run your script with the virtual environment activated

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, even in a venv...